# why my localhost website folder redirected to localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, xampp, localhost

i had setup a site on localhost xampp.

```
i.e. http://localhost/dance
but some of the pages redirected to http://localhost/page1.shtml
but i want them redirect to http://localhost/dance/page1.shtml
```

**My htaccess file**

```
#this url rewriting is to run on local server
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
#the above code is converting all .php extension to blank.

#for root category page
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.shtml$ root.php?roottitle=$1
#http://www.micsafrica.com/pagename.shtml


#for main category page
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.shtml$ main.php?roottitle=$1&maintitle=$2

#for news page
RewriteRule ^news/(.+) news.php?news_id=$1 [nc]
#http://www.micsafrica.com/news/25


#for individual project page
RewriteRule ^project/(.+) project.php?project_id=$1 [nc]
#http://www.micsafrica.com/project/25
```

**HTML Links are**

```
<a href="/page1.shtml"></a>
<a href="/page2.shtml"></a>
<a href="/page3.shtml"></a>
```

so is there any need to set base url in localhost htaccess, if yes than please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: The links you've made are relative to the host (start with a /). Update the links to be e.g. /dance/page1.shtml or use page relative links.

Comment: but now i have update whole site so is there another way to do this..

Comment: There are, but they're all massively overkill for the sake of updating a few links.

Comment: not possible to changes all the links...

Comment: You're building on your local machine and can't change all the links? That seems unlikely. If you really must, you can add rewrite rules for those specific pages to 301 redirect to the correct locations.